# count elements in database with xpath query

Tags: sql-server, xpath

I have a table of users groups. Each record contains an xml field "MyDocument" composed of a list of users.

```
<MyDocument>
  <Users>
    <User name="Kevin">
    </User>
    <User name="David">
    </User>
  </Users>
</MyDocument>
```

I would like to count all the record which contains at least one user called "Kevin". This is what I have done
until now :

```
select count (*) 
from UsersGroups 
where MyDocument.value('(/MyDocument/Users/User/@name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') like 'Kevin'
```

The problem with this query is that it's only checking the first User element, for example if my user called Kevin appears in the second or any other
position than the first it won't be counted.

The second problem that I am having is the case problem. I have to count only the user called Kevin and not kevin or KEVIN.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is expand your nodes using the `nodes()` xquery function, so that you can check all the names. Then simply use a case sensitive collation for your equals check:

```
DECLARE @UsersGroups TABLE (MyDocument XML);
INSERT @UsersGroups VALUES ('<MyDocument>
  <Users>
    <User name="Kevin"></User>
    <User name="David"></User>
    <User name="KEVIN"></User>
    <User name="kevin"></User>
    <User name="Kevin"></User>
  </Users>
</MyDocument>');

SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    @UsersGroups AS ug
        CROSS APPLY ug.MyDocument.nodes('/MyDocument/Users/User') x (UserName)
WHERE   x.UserName.value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'Kevin' COLLATE latin1_general_cs_as;
```

Alternatively you can use the [`exist()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) function, which, since xqyuery is case sensitive will have the desired behaviour with stating the collation:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    @UsersGroups AS ug
        CROSS APPLY ug.MyDocument.nodes('/MyDocument/Users/User') x (UserName)
WHERE   x.UserName.exist('.[@name = "Kevin"]') = 1;
```

**ADDENDUM**

Using like, you could either extract the name using `value()` and compare using `LIKE`, or use `exist()` and switch to the [contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178026.aspx) function:

```
DECLARE @UsersGroups TABLE (MyDocument XML);
INSERT @UsersGroups VALUES ('<MyDocument>
  <Users>
    <User name="Kevin"></User>
    <User name="David"></User>
    <User name="KEVIN"></User>
    <User name="kevin"></User>
    <User name="test Kevin"></User>
  </Users>
</MyDocument>');

SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    @UsersGroups AS ug
        CROSS APPLY ug.MyDocument.nodes('/MyDocument/Users/User') x (UserName)
WHERE   x.UserName.value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') LIKE '%Kevin%' COLLATE latin1_general_cs_as;


SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    @UsersGroups AS ug
        CROSS APPLY ug.MyDocument.nodes('/MyDocument/Users/User') x (UserName)
WHERE   x.UserName.exist('.[contains (@name, "Kevin")]') = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed andswer. I would like to know if it's also possible no to use a equal = but a contains, as my user name could be composed of the name but also other things, for example name ="15 Kevin test"

Comment: I am trying your answer but I am getting an error 'invalid object name on ug.MyDocument.nodes

Comment: Are you running the same query I have posted? Based on your question you should just be able to remove the `@` from the start of `@UsersGroups` from my query, and it should work fine. If not please can you post the query you are running. I would guess it is something as simple as I have given the table an alias of `ug` whereas you have not.